# More narrow type is not assignable to other

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

There two types:

```
type ExcludeString<T = any> = Exclude<T, string>;
type ExcludeStringAndBoolean<T = any> = Exclude<T, string | boolean>;
```

In the code of the function

```
function test1<T>(p: ExcludeStringAndBoolean<T>) {
  let a: ExcludeString<T>;
  a = p;
}
```

tsc throws an error for line `a = p`

```
Type 'Exclude<T, string | boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<T, string>'.ts(2322)
```

But for the certain use it works very well:

```
type CertainType = string | number | boolean;

function test2(p: ExcludeStringAndBoolean<CertainType>) {
  let a: ExcludeString<CertainType>;
  a = p;
}
```

Why is it like this?

Comment: Interesting case. Copied the code to the TS playground out of curiosity: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmEDKwBOBLAOwHMAeAFSgF4oBDAkAPitkVQ3IBooBnXQohgG4AUKEgtk6LH2IBBAmgBCAe2VIIdcszqNm8SezJde+YlAA+UAEar1dIcOEZkNHNABmKAgmB5lBKGAIXgBGcgYACjAALgk2aVMieSVbDQJwgEooAG9hKCh1YFpY-XjsRPCRfJpmMBEAX0cAeiaoAFoOzq7unt6+-v7HMWgAYQgcYBpCMnBoahN+CygCFABbK3GlmzU0kU9vX39A4OAAJiiS1ily-mSVHc0xiamCGcgGLNz8wuK465lSE9JtNZg5qrUGsIgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exclude` is a conditional type. If a conditional type contains an unresolved type parameter (such as `T`) typescript will not try to reason much about the conditional type. So the assignability rules become pretty restrictive.

For `Exclude`, if the second parameters are different (ie the type tested against is different) the assignability check fails (such as `string | boolean` vs `string` in your case) . If the first parameters (ie the tested type) has a type relation, the assignment succeeds. So for example this will work:

```
type ExcludeString<T = any> = Exclude<T, string>;
type ExcludeStringAndBoolean<T = any> = Exclude<T, string | boolean>;

function test1<T extends U, U>(p: ExcludeString<T>) {
  let a: ExcludeString<U>;
  a = p;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmEDKwBOBLAOwHMAeAFSgF4oBDAkAPitkVQ3IBooBnXQohgG4AUKEgtk6LH2IBBAmgBCAe2VIIdcszqNm8SezJde+YlAA+UAEar1dIcOEAzFAQTA8yglGAReARi0IOF8FbigAVS4IhgAKMAAuCTZpU1IyBgBKKABvYSgodWBaJP0U7DSSGJECmmYwEQBfRwB6FqgAWi7unt6+-oHBwccxaABhCBxgGkIycGhqE34LKAIUAFsrSZWbNQ0CERc3Dy8fP2AAJnjS1ikK-nklW32SCamZgjnILNz8wohijQbgZUvxXpNprN5g5avUmsIgA)

Comment: Can you supplement your answer with a link to the documentation page if it exists on the Typescript site?

Comment: @AndreiKovalev I wish I could. Most of the really arcane type stuff is only on GH and is not really easy to find. The conditional type compatibility I came across here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-524631270 where the commenter mentions he got it from a compiler code comment ... so I guess official  ? 